# How to write a Movie Booking application codes for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Design a Movie Booking application that

1. Allows user to browse movie listing (of at least 10 movies) with image and description;
2. When user selects a movie, show him the seats available;
3. User may choose the seats by clicking on them;
4. User may de-select a seat by clicking on a selected seat;
5. When user clicks a “Book” button, display his booking info and total price;
6. When user clicks “OK”, update the record and the seats will not be available to subsequent user.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements I deduce that you're project is just a simple database application with a graphical user interface.

For that purpose I recommend the following.

1. Learn about databases and SQL, how to define tables, select data, store and retrieve photos, etc. Put and special emphasis on [JDBC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm), since this would be done in java. You're first step could very well be to define a database squema.
2. Learn about Swing, how to define your GUI, how to react to GUI events, such as clicking a button, etc. [Here](http://www.javabeginner.com/java-swing/java-swing-tutorial) is a good begginers toturial, that will help you to get the GUI part of your project ready.

Answer (score 0):

Do the interface first. I wouldn't even bother with the DB to begin with.  I would simply have a simple array with the movie title and the start times.

The DB would be the last thing I would recommend attempting.

Really though if you are attempting this part of the course already and you don't know the basics of Java & Swing then you should make sure you turn up to lectures first!